# Scanning into an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to scan a word after which following pressing enter it would get placed in the nth position in a ArrayList using a for loop. Where do I place the (i) in this code to make it work? I can't put it in like so can I topScan.next(i);?

```
for ( int i = 0; i>topsNo; i++); {
    System.out.println("Enter next topping :");
    Scanner topScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    b.currentTops = topScan.next();
}
```

EDIT:

I made it unclear therefore I'm going to add the rest of the class:

```
public static void main(String [] Args) {
PizzaBase a = new PizzaBase();
Pizza p = new Pizza();
PizzaToppings b = new PizzaToppings();


//SCAN FOR KEYWORD INGRIDIENTS TO SEE WHAT IS OK


Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String base;
System.out.println("Enter base: ");

base = s.next();
a.setBase(base);

int topsNo = 0;

System.out.println("Enter number of desired toppings: ");
Scanner nt = new Scanner(System.in);

if(nt.hasNextInt()){
       topsNo = nt.nextInt();
    }else{
       System.out.println("Try again (re-enter number of toppings 1-9)");
    }
```

EDIT: As requested, the PizzaToppings class:

```
public class PizzaToppings {


List<String> tops = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Double> prices = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<String> currentTops = new ArrayList<String>();
double topPrice;
public void pizzaTop() {

    currentTops.add("mushrooms");
    currentTops.add("cheese");
    currentTops.add("ham");
    currentTops.add("chicken");

    for(int i = 0; i<currentTops.size(); i++){

    if(currentTops.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("cheese")){ 
           topPrice+=(1.0);
       } else if(currentTops.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("sweetcorn")){
           topPrice+=(2.0);
       } else if(currentTops.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("mushrooms")){
           topPrice+=(1.2);
       } else if(currentTops.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("chicken")){
           topPrice+=(1.25);
       }
       else{
           System.out.println("Sorry but topping "+ currentTops.get(i)
                + " cannot be offered.");
           break;
       }
     }


}
```

Comment: What is `topsNo` ?? What is `b`  ?

Comment: You dont have to create a new scanner each time you iterate...

Comment: Where do you receive the index where you want to put it into? It doesn't say here.

Comment: If you want to delimit each value with `enter`, then you should use `nextLine()`.

Comment: I've added the whole class. Should be clearer now

Comment: Your question is about `ArrayList` but I don't see a single one in there. What exactly is the problem you're having? What is `b.currentTops`?

Comment: Please post the code of the `PizzaToppings` Class.

Comment: Added PizzaToppings class

Comment: Use `list.set(n, string)`, `n` being the index you want to place a new string at

Comment: @peeskillet I don't quite understand where to do this. Could you please enter it into the code?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish. I'm not sure I completely understand.

Comment: Why not just `b.currentTops.add(topScan.nextLine());`? And as someone suggested, no need to create a new `Scanner` every iteration. Instead put the Scanner outside of the loop

Comment: @peeskillet That code won't work because I'm trying to get each value (topping) I type in to be assigned into a list - type in ham (press enter) cheese (enter) pepperoni (enter) and the list currentTops will be [ham], [cheese], [pepperoni]

Comment: Sorry, but I really have no idea what your code is trying t accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to iterate through the [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) until the user entered number of toppings have been added. Here is some code to do this. Also, you don't need to create a new Scanner each time you use it, so I changed that.

```
    Scanner theKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String base;
    System.out.println("Enter base: ");

    base = theKeyboard.next();
    a.setBase(base);



    System.out.println("Enter number of desired toppings: ");
    int topsNo = theKeyboard.nextInt();

    //Alternately use a while loop here incrementing 'i' each time a topping is entered
    for (int i = 0; i < topsNo; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter next topping :");
        b.currentTops = theKeyboard.next();
    }
```